# Как я могу поставить пробелы в string cout?

Tags: c++, строки, cin

> Решил сделать простенькую фановую игру на плюсах только начиная его изучать, добрался до Стринга, а вот как пробелы ставить в моём случае я не знаю, пытался искать но находил только для других задач, а тут как?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void main() {
string d;
cout << "Start game? y, n" << endl;
cin >> d;
if (d == "y")
{
    cout << "You are Freddy Fazbear" << endl;
    cin >> d;
}
        if (d == "Room for parties")
```

Comment: Читайте строку с помощью `getline`.